# How can fit a large table vertical with a picture?

Tags: beamer, tabularx, adjustbox, supertabular

I use column package to split sile to 2 column. one for picture and one for table.
But my table was broken. Please help me fix it. Here is my code:

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[height = 2 cm]{demo}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{      
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Method& RMSE & MAE & MSE & NMSE & MAPE &Hit Rate \%\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{1-step ahead}\\
        \hline
            PureNN & 5.6411 & 4.1652 & 31.8224 & 0.015 & 0.0094 & 51.61\\
            WaveletNN&5.5612&4.0539&30.9271&0.0146&0.0091&53.63\\

        \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{3-step ahead}\\
        \hline
            PureNN & 11.8207 & 9.0218 & 139.7278 & 0.0658 & 0.0202 & 52.23\\        
            WaveletNN&10.0794&7.4881&101.5934&0.0478&0.0169&53.04\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{4-step ahead}\\
        \hline
            PureNN & 12.212 & 9.3179 & 149.1321 & 0.0702 & 0.0212 & 49.6\\
            WaveletNN&12.0099&9.0578&144.2389&0.0679&0.0205&52.4\\

        \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{7-step ahead}\\
        \hline
            PureNN & 16.6392 & 13.35 & 276.8621 & 0.1303 & 0.0304 & 49.80\\
            WaveletNN&15.824&12.3698&250.4003&0.1179&0.0278&55.82\\
        \hline
        \end{tabularx}  }
    \end{column}

  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here my result(not right!!!):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking `tabularx` to force the table to the original line width *before* you scale it, which would mean making the width of the X column negative so it gives up.

Just use a normal table to arbitrary width, then scale it.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[height = 2 cm]{demo}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%,, don't forget this %   
        \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Method& RMSE & MAE & MSE & NMSE & MAPE &Hit Rate \%\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{1-step ahead}\\
        \hline
            PureNN & 5.6411 & 4.1652 & 31.8224 & 0.015 & 0.0094 & 51.61\\
            WaveletNN&5.5612&4.0539&30.9271&0.0146&0.0091&53.63\\

        \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{3-step ahead}\\
        \hline
            PureNN & 11.8207 & 9.0218 & 139.7278 & 0.0658 & 0.0202 & 52.23\\        
            WaveletNN&10.0794&7.4881&101.5934&0.0478&0.0169&53.04\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{4-step ahead}\\
        \hline
            PureNN & 12.212 & 9.3179 & 149.1321 & 0.0702 & 0.0212 & 49.6\\
            WaveletNN&12.0099&9.0578&144.2389&0.0679&0.0205&52.4\\

        \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{7-step ahead}\\
        \hline
            PureNN & 16.6392 & 13.35 & 276.8621 & 0.1303 & 0.0304 & 49.80\\
            WaveletNN&15.824&12.3698&250.4003&0.1179&0.0278&55.82\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}%don't forget this %
         }
    \end{column}

  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```